# frei0r filters not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I've installed ffmpeg on a new server, but the `frei0r` filters don't seem to be working for some reason. I just installed it from the standard `apt` repo on Ubuntu 20.04, like I did with my old server, but it just isn't working for some reason.

I tried it on the static johnvansickle builds as well, still had the same issue.

My ffmpeg comes with these libraries:

```
 configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
```

As you can see, `--enable-frei0r` is listed there, but every time I want to use a filter of theirs, I get this error:

```
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x560789f97440] Could not find module 'glow'.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x560789f396c0] Error initializing filter 'frei0r' with args 'levels:0.4'
```

`glow` can be replaced with any other `frei0r` filter and still have the same issue. I would appreciate any help

The command I used:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -vf "frei0r=pixeliz0r:0.02" output.mp4
```

The output I received:

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.4-1ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'input.webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:24.36, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 741 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/unknown/unknown), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:24.323000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:00:24.361000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (vp9 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (opus (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[Parsed_frei0r_0 @ 0x563958b7c780] Could not find module 'pixeliz0r'.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x563958b79700] Error initializing filter 'frei0r' with args 'pixeliz0r:0.02'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[aac @ 0x563958a45240] Qavg: 9612.982
[aac @ 0x563958a45240] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: Where are frei0r modules installed? Also you can do glow with ffmpeg filters combination alone with much better quality then frei0r.

Comment: @llogan I've updated my question. Thanks for replying

Comment: @llogan Any other ideas on what I should try then? `ffmpeg -filters` shows `frei0r` listed there, it just returns that error when I actually try to run something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the **frei0r-plugins** package:

```
sudo apt install frei0r-plugins
```

Comment: Thanks! I just assumed that it would've been automatically installed (like all the other libraries) with `sudo apt install ffmpeg`, but for whatever weird reason, it wasn't here. Specifically installing it worked instantly for me.

Comment: @pigeonburger Yeah, frei0r-plugins should be a dependency of the libavfilter package on Ubuntu. You can submit a bug report to Ubuntu.

Comment: Weird... it's not listed as a dependency here: https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal-updates/libavfilter7 I'll report it anyway as it probably should be.... thanks again